# Find busy line while calling with Asterisk

Tags: java, asterisk, fastagi

I am using this code for making a call with *Asterisk*:

```
exec("DIAL", "DAHDI/g0/" + phoneNo + "," + timeOut + ",mg,");
```

But this snippet always return 0.
How can I find the phone line is busy or not answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i have inform you that that line return 1 if dial can't be done(but yes, that is rare situation).

For result please check dial command page:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial

It return DIALSTATUS dialplan variable.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variable+DIALSTATUS

Answer (score 1):

For those who use [Asterisk jav](https://github.com/asterisk-java/asterisk-java)a

```
String status = channel.getVariable("DIALSTATUS");
```

status will give you status of dial, such as BUSY, NOANSWER described
https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variable+DIALSTATUS